# Converting Data table to Generic List does not use decimal separator Information from culture and uses period(.) as a separator always

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, currentculture

I have written an extension method to convert the Datatable to a generic observable collection as below:

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this DataTable dt)
        {

            var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Select(c => c.ColumnName.ToUpperInvariant())
                .ToList();

            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            List<T> returnList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
            {
                var objT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

                foreach (var pro in properties)
                {
                    if (columnNames.Contains(pro.Name.ToUpperInvariant()))
                    {
                        if (row[pro.Name] != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToString(row[pro.Name]) != string.Empty)
                        {
                            if ((pro.PropertyType == Type.GetType("System.Boolean")) || (row[pro.Name].GetType() == Type.GetType("System.Boolean")))
                                pro.SetValue(objT, Convert.ToBoolean(row[pro.Name]), null);

                            else if (row[pro.Name].GetType() == Type.GetType("System.Int64"))
                                pro.SetValue(objT, Convert.ToInt32(row[pro.Name]), null);
                            else
                                pro.SetValue(objT, row[pro.Name], System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default, null, null, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return objT;
            }).ToList();
```

I have set the decimal symbol to Comma(,) in my machine([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipGbF.png)) and the Number Format in the CurrentCulture of my application is having the same([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrZhJ.png)).

The data table returned from the database also has the decimal values where the decimal separator is comma(,) [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLkJj.png)

When i convert this data table to observable collection using the method above i get the Observable collection which has the decimal value but instead of having the decimal separator comma(,) i see period(.) as a decimal separator.

What am i missing here?

Please let me know if my question is not clear. I'll add more details accordingly.

I tried to reproduce this behavior using the sample WPF application and i am getting comma(,) as the decimal separator when i do ToString() on the property and then display it in a label. if i don't do ToString() then period(.) is being used as a decimal separator([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIas7.png))

Tried the solution provided in [Rick Strahl's Web Log](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Jun/14/WPF-Bindings-and-CurrentCulture-Formatting) but it didn't help as well.

Comment: In which display do you look at the decimal values?

Comment: @GertArnold In WPF application (in Label bound to a property).

Comment: Well, apparently it's got a different culture. The display format is in no way an intrinsic attribute of a decimal value, the display culture rules.

Comment: @GertArnold I tried to reproduce using a sample application. when i use ToString() on the property then comma(,) is used as the decimal separator else period(.) is used.